# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: while using YouTube API

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

```
11-26 15:50:58.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3199): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.PlayMedia
11-26 15:50:58.159: E/AndroidRuntime(3199):     at com.android.Description.onClick(Description.java:63)
```

LIne Number 63

```
startActivity(new Intent(Description.this,PlayMedia.class));
```

**PlayMedia.java**

```
public class PlayMedia extends  YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.play_media);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);



}
@Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
            boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo("wKJ9KzGQq0w");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    }
}
```

**YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity.java**(Provided by Youtube itself)

```
public abstract class YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

  private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

  @Override
  public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
      YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
    if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
      errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
    } else {
      String errorMessage = String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
      Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
      // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
      getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }
  }

  protected abstract YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider();

}
```

I have registered the activity `PlayMedia` in my `Manifest` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it.Mark all checkboxes.Click on Apply and clean the project.

This worked for me.Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you use any external jars?

Comment: Yes,you have to do that..:-)